# How can I search across Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, match, formula, vlookup

I want to transfer data automatically from 2 sheets to one single combining one. That means I have 2 different export sheets (called 'Te_open' and 'Te_closed') that contain both the columns "Problem" (in different positions, can vary always). I have one sheet, that represents an overview of the data from the two other export sheets. So when I have for example the value "Te1" in the cell A2 of my overview sheet, I want Excel to search in the two export sheets the value "Te1" and give back the value in the same row as "Te1" but of the column "Problem", so that I can fill the cell B2 where I want to have the Problem type. So I thought I might need the "MATCH" formula, to let excel know I want to search the column with the headline "Problem" in the export sheets, to fill the column "Problem" in my overview sheet.

The problem that I see is that I have to search TWO sheets and I don't know in which one the "Pm1" will appear. Furthermore I don't know in which column of the sheet "Problem" will appear.

Can you please help me? I would preferably like to solve the problem with a formula, not a macro. Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,
question

Comment: Is the value that you're searching for (e.g. 'Te1' in your example) always in column A, but it could be in column A of 'Te_open' or column A of 'Te_closed'? How do you identify 'the columns "Problem" (in different position, can vary always)' - do you mean the column you want to refer to has the text 'Problem' in row 1?

Comment: Exactly, I always search for the column with the test 'Problem' in the first row. @nekomatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the index of the first column in one of your sheets that is headed 'Problem', you can use (e.g.):

```
=MATCH("Problem",Te_open!$1:$1,0)
```

Let's assume we place that formula in a cell somewhere and name the cell `open_col`. To find a value in column A of `Te_open` and return the corresponding value from the 'Problem' column, you can then use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Te_open!$A$2:$Z$999,open_col)
```

Note that you'll have to define the search range to include the largest range that your data on `Te_open` could occupy. If the search value is found this will return the corresponding value from the 'Problem' column, otherwise it'll return `#N/A`. So if you've also set up a cell called `closed_col` to get the column index for the `Te_closed` sheet, you can do:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Te_open!$A$2:$Z$999,open_col)),VLOOKUP(A2,Te_closed!$A$2:$Z$999,closed_col),VLOOKUP(A2,Te_open!$A$2:$Z$999,open_col)
```

That gets the result from the correct column of `Te_open` if the search value was found there, otherwise it gets the result from the correct column of `Te_closed`. If neither sheet contains the search value it'll return `#N/A`.